# How can I inject an object into an WCF IErrorHandler implementation with Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, ierrorhandler

I'm developing a set of services using WCF. The application is doing dependency injection with Castle Windsor. I've added an `IErrorHandler` implementation that is added to services via an attribute. Everything is working thus far. The `IErrorHandler` object (of a class called `FaultHandler` is being applied properly and invoked.

Now I'm adding logging. Castle Windsor is set up to inject the logger object (an instance of `IOurLogger`). This is working. But when I try to add it to `FaultHandler` my logger is null.

The code for `FaultHandler` looks something like this:

```
class FaultHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    public IOurLogger logger { get; set; }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        logger.Write("Exception type {0}. Message: {1}", error.GetType(), error.Message);

        // Let WCF handle things its way. We only want to log.
        return false;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, Message fault)
    {
    }
}
```

This throws it's own exception, since `logger` is null when `HandleError()` is called.

The logger is being successfully injected into the service itself and is usable there, but for some reason I can't use it in `FaultHandler`.

**Update**: Here is the relevant part of the Windsor configuration file (edited to protect the innocent):

```
<configuration>
  <components>
    <component id="Logger"
               service="Our.Namespace.IOurLogger, Our.Namespace"
               type="Our.Namespace.OurLogger, Our.Namespace"
    />
  </components>
</configuration>
```